# How to shift down elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, move, element

My problem is really simple though I can't find a efficient way to solve it.
I Want to load a new element in the first position of a list and then, shift down the other elements.

For example, I got a list L of 3 elements

```
L=list("a","b","c")
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"
```

I got a string "z", and I want to load it into the first element of my list L, so the expected new list NL would look like to :

```
[[1]]
[1] "z"

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] "b"

[[4]]
[1] "c"
```

Anybody knows how to do it in an elegant way? Thanks!!

Comment: Oops ! I'm sorry, I didn't find it because of my poor english I think.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but rather expensive, to use `append` function:

```
append(list("z"), L)
```

Still, extending data structures in plain R is something you want to avoid most of the time. If you have algorithm that requires this kind of operation it is better to use [RCpp](http://www.rcpp.org/).

Otherwise it is better to pre-allocate a larger structure and simply fill the values.

Comment: I think you're waay overthinking this question

Comment: append is fine, really no need for RCpp

Comment: @rawr Maybe a little. Somehow the simple fact that `list` is not really a lists makes me anxious :)

Comment: When is a list not a list?  When it's an R list?

Comment: @Richard Scriven I mean good old linked list:  `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3)))`